# get sub_field from children pages and sort them alphabetically

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, html-lists, alphabetical

I'm using a php code to display children pages from a specific parent page ID to display page links in a select list type.

all my children pages have a sub_field called "artiste", with an artist name.

here is my php code to display the page name with link to the page :

```
<?php

        $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'page',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_parent'    => '22',
        'order'          => 'ASC',
        'orderby'        => 'title'
        );

        $parent = new WP_Query( $args );

        if ( $parent->have_posts() ) : ?>

        <div class="styled-select">

            <select name="" onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">

            <?php while ( $parent->have_posts() ) : $parent->the_post(); ?>



                    <option value="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></option>



            <?php endwhile; ?>

            </select>

        </div>

        <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

this works fine, I get all the children page titles and the permalink and sorted alphabetically.

now I want to get instead of the page title, a custom field from each children pages, here is my code :
my custom field is "the_sub_field('nom_artiste');"

```
        $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'page',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_parent'    => '22',
        'order'          => 'ASC',
        'orderby'        => 'title'
        );

        $parent = new WP_Query( $args );

        if ( $parent->have_posts() ) : ?>

        <div class="styled-select">

            <select name="" onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">

            <option>--- A - Z ---</option>



            <?php while ( $parent->have_posts() ) : $parent->the_post(); ?>



                    <option value="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php if(get_field('artiste')): while (has_sub_field('artiste') ): ?><?php the_sub_field('nom_artiste'); ?><?php endwhile; endif; ?></option>



            <?php endwhile; ?>


            </select>

        </div>

        <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

it works also, I get the custom field instead of the page title, and the permalink of my page title, that's perfect.

but in this second code, my custom field are sorted depending of there page title.

for example, I have 2 pages :

AAAAA

ZZZZZ

and custom fields :

for AAAA : custom field is GGGG

for ZZZZ : custom field is BBBB

so with the second php code, my list is not sorted right because it sorted depending on the page title and not of custom field... I get :

GGGG

BBBB

I think I have to create an array with my custom field to be abble to sort them alphabetically before displaying them in my select onchange, but I don't know how to do it...

can anybody help me with this ?

thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try this, replacing everything between `<?php while ... endwhile; ?>` in your code:

```
<?php
   //Declare an array to hold data
   $options = array();

   //The loop
   while ( $parent->have_posts() ) : $parent->the_post();
       //Define a temporary array
       $option = array();

       //Get all the values we need and store them in an array.
       $option['value'] = get_permalink();
       $option['title'] = get_the_title();
       if(get_field('artiste')): 
           while (has_sub_field('artiste') ) {
              $option['label'] = get_sub_field('nom_artiste'); 
           }
       else: 
           $option['label'] = get_the_title(); //Put something here if artiste is not populated.
       endif;
       $options[] = $option;
    endwhile;

    //Sort the array on the 'label' field
    usort($options, function($a, $b) { return strcmp($a['label'], $b['label']); });

    //Output the <option> tags
    $format = '          <option value="%s" title="%s">%s</option>'."\n";
    foreach ($options as $o) {
         printf($format, $o['value'], $o['title'], $o['label']);
    }
?>
```